# Arduino Webcam live stream with agora.io

Tags: arduino, agora.io

I am looking to stream video (obviously 1 way) from an Arduino ESP32-cam through agora.io to a client app/web.  Is there an agora API or workaround (hopefully REST with an example) that I could stream the images from the Arduino board? Any alternative suggestions would also be appreciated.

Comment: Google "esp32 cam web server", there are plenty of info on how to build a web server and serve the content, all you need to modify is to setup the route that meet the agora.io REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Agora doesn't offer any RESTful API for sending video in the way you are describing. [You may want to consider using the Agora C++ SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/cpp/index.html).

If you are using Arduino and ESP32, there's this tutorial on how to set up a streaming server,  https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-video-streaming-web-server-camera-home-assistant but it doesn't use Agora's tech.